# Rails PJAX not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have added the pjax javascript.

In my view I have:

```
<div data-pjax-container>
<%= yield %>
</div>
```

But still onclick the hole page updates.

Comment: From the Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax) it looks like that piece should be in application.html.erb and `<div data-pjax-container>
  ...
</div>`
should be in the view

Comment: I have added it to the view know. It still does not work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have included this line in **app/assets/javascript/applications.js**:

```
//= require jquery.pjax
```

Add an id attribute to the div:

```
<div id="target_pjax_container" data-pjax-container>
<%= yield %>
</div>
```

And make an explicit call to a pjax div from a link in your views:

```
<%= link_to 'user', user_path, :'data-pjax' => '#target_pjax_container' %>
```

**Note:**

The gem used is **'pjax_rails'**. Always check that javascript isn't broken (with firebug or equivalent -  You can also use it to sniff the network and view the pjax request).

Comment: I would say PJAX is a bit outdated when there is TURBOLINKS now.

Comment: @Railsbeginner i missed it.. going to read now https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to add the line:

`//= require pjax`

to **app/assets/application.js**?